# Connection between two UIButtons programmatically

Tags: iphone, uibutton

Connected rewindButton with playButton programmatically. rewindButton is simply rewinding and playing from the beginning and playButton toggles from play to pause.In the rewindButton method used statement to change the UIImage of UIButton2 when UIButton1 is pressed. That is working fine.

PlayButton method is working fine when play button is pressed and paused. Even after resuming is working fine.

Issue briefing:

When rewindButton is pressed it will change the UIImage of playButton to PauseImage so that user can pause. Problem arises when pause is resumed. `When pause is resumed it is reloading view controllers.`It should load viewcontrollers only for the first time as per code.

```
-(void)rewind:(id)sender{
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
[timer invalidate];
ContainerViewController *viewController = [[[ContainerViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[audioPlayer play];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                    target:self
                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
    [_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
 }



-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {

if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
    [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];

}else{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];

   if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                            target:self
                                            selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime  = NO;
    } 
    } 
    }

- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{  

 First *first = [[First alloc] init];
 first.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 425);
 CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];   
 [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
 [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];    
 [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction     functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];    
 [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];   
   [self.view addSubview:first.view];
 [first release];   
 self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(Second) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];     
 }

-(void)Second 
{
Second *second = [[Second alloc] init];
second.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 425);
CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];
[transitionAnimation setDuration:1]; 
[transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionReveal];
[self.view addSubview:second.view]; 
[second release];
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(Third) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Comment: Why are uou repeating your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason it was reloading view controllers after resuming cause in the rewind method i forgot to add isFirstTime == YES for loading view controllers. Viewcontrollers are not required to reload. Viewcontrollers are required to start loading from the beginning only for the first time only.

So after setting the value of isFirstTime == YES in rewind method now it is not reloading view controllers from the beginning after it is resumed from the pause.

```
-(void)rewind:(id)sender{
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
[timer invalidate];
ContainerViewController *viewController = [[[ContainerViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[audioPlayer play];
if(isFirstTime == YES){
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                target:self
                                selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
 isFirstTime  = NO;
}

[_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
 }
```

Now it is working fine.